# How do I make an if statement where the condition is gameobject at coordinates in Unity 2d C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there something like this that checks the location of a game object?

```
if (gameobject.location == 0, 0, 0){
    }
```

Comment: I know this question may seem stupid but I have tried and searched for a long time and can't find the answer anywhere. PLEASE ANYONE who knows PLEASE tell me.

Answer (score 3):

you can compare the position of the transform. Beware that you should never compare floating point numbers directly to each other. It's better to check if the distance is below some small threshold.

```cs
Vector3 yourCoordinates = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, yourCoordinates ) < 0.001f) {
         Debug.Log("distance below threshold");
     }
```

Comment: rbcode, I tried and didn't work for me. I'm trying to make an endless runner game.

Comment: @Expecto The code works and provides exactly what you asked for. Maybe you should follow some tutorials before trying to make your own game with what seems very little knowledge about Unity.

Comment: Yeah this code works. If it's not triggering in your specific application then either your threshold for your gameobject's distance from the coordinates is too small, or your object is not where you think it is.